# conditional filtering excel macros

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded this macro where I make 3 filters, (by status, by substatus, and by country) once completed I want to save the results in a new spreadsheet with a custom name, the issue is when any of the option filter does not exist.

for example, if "costa rica" does not exist in the selection I get and weird result, in the event costa rica does not exist I would like to still create the new file but only copy and paste fist row of the original file into the new file.

Please help.

```
Sub filtrado()

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SEGUIMIENTO").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1 _
        :="Closed"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SEGUIMIENTO").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1 _
        :=Array("In Progress", "Pending", "Pending Customer", "Updated by Customer"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SEGUIMIENTO").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1 _
        :="Costa Rica"
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Put some pictures of your table and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there are any visible rows so that you can copy the data.

```
Sub filtrado2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim ol As ListObject: Set ol = ws.ListObjects("SEGUIMIENTO")
    Dim olCol As Integer
    Dim srcRng As Range, dstRng As Range
    
    ' filter column 2
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Column2").Index
    ol.Range.AutoFilter Field:=olCol, Criteria1:="Closed"
    
    ' filter column 3
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Column3").Index
    ol.Range.AutoFilter Field:=olCol, Criteria1 _
        :=Array("In Progress", "Pending", "Pending Customer", "Updated by Customer"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
        
    ' filter column 5
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Column5").Index
    ol.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Costa Rica1"
    
    ' check visible rows
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim olRowsVisible As Integer
    olRowsVisible = ol.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' copy only if any rows visible
    If olRowsVisible > 0 Then
        Set srcRng = Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)    ' copies the table header and visible rows
        Set dstRng = ws.Range("N1")
        
        srcRng.Copy dstRng
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
        
End Sub
```